# Trying to add link on d365 model driven app to show all items in a specific queue

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am working in Dynamics 365 online and working inside a model driven app, I'm adding a link on the left side navigation that takes them to a page displaying all items within a specific queue.

However I can only seem to take them to a page that shows All Items I Am Working on, and under that Queues I'm a member of.

No one is a member of any queue since they are public.  I just want a simple way to show them all of the queue items inside a specific queue once they click "Physical Mail".

I tried creating a specific view, but since the queue item filter defaults to "Queues I'm a member of" this doesn't work for me.

Is what I am wanting to do possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's very straightforward: when looking at the specific view that you want, copy the URL from the address bar and put it in the Sitemap as "URL" instead of "Entity".

(If the view that you want does not exist, you'll have to first of all create it, of course).